# Api documentation generated from Swashbuckle shows wrong scheme (HTTP instead of HTTPS)

Tags: c#, swashbuckle

Our Web API setup is done in an Azure kubernetes cluster with nginx as ingress controller and Lets encrypt for https.
In the staging namespace all is fine, the swagger UI is accesible using https and the server shows the server as https as well.
The same setup on prod namespace shows the swagger ui as https but the server as http only. Also try to execute any API functions fails.

Any idea what can go wrong with passinge the scheme information from nginx to the service running the API? As far as I know the communication between nginx and the service is http only.
The docker image for the server is the same and the ingresses for staging and prod only differ service names and host names.

Best regards

Comment: Documentation may be old.  Most servers in the last couple of years are requiring HTTPS.

Comment: were you able to fix it?

Comment: Not yet :-( this behavior is still a mystery for me.